# java.util.InputMismatchException when Scanning from a txt file

Tags: java, string, class, input, int

So I must create a program that deals with flight passengers which I have to scan in from a .txt file in java using a class that specifically handles each passenger's data as it is stored in the .txt file.

I am running into a few issues using Dr. Java to code this program, I am currently receiving the error in my title when I try to read the 'age' value as an int from the txt.

I am also trying to read in each individual line using a nested while loop so that I can assign each value separated by a comma with its associated variable. I know that one way to do this is by parsing each individual line and by counting the commas, but some lines of the txt file as you can see below have 3 commas and some have 2. So I am unsure of the best way to handle this.
Any help supplied is appreciated.

```
.txt file information is:

Theresa Ann Grabowski,7B,40,Gluten-intolerant
Allison Debra Lewis,12C,38,Extra crunchy
David R. Parker,3A,49,Jain 
Stephen Post,5A,49,Extra crunchy
Emily Post,5B,12
Deborah George,9C,9,Gluten-intolerant
Allen George,8A,88
```

Here is the code for my 'passengers' class:

```
public class Passengers
{
  private String full_name, seat_class, seat_num, meal_plan;
  private int age;

  public Passengers(String name, String s_class, int age, String seat, String meal)
  {
    full_name=name;
    seat_num=seat;
    age=age;
    seat_class=s_class;
    meal_plan=meal;
  }




  public String toString()
  {
    return "Full Name: "+full_name+" Seat Class: "+seat_class+" Seat Number: "+seat_num+" Meal Preference: "+meal_plan+"";
  }
```

Here is the code with main method:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Flight
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("PassengerList.txt"));
    String full_name, seat_class, seat_num, meal_plan;
    int age, counter=0;




    Passengers[] passengers = new Passengers[33];

    scan.useDelimiter(",|\\r|\\n");

    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
      String line = scan.nextLine();
      while(scan.hasNext())
    {
      full_name=scan.next();
      seat_num=scan.next();
      age=scan.nextInt();
      seat_class=scan.next();
      meal_plan=scan.next();
      passengers[counter]=new Passengers(full_name,seat_class,age,seat_num,meal_plan);
      }
      counter++;
    }



   for (int forcounter=0; forcounter<33; forcounter++)

    System.out.println(passengers[forcounter]); }
}
```

error:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Flight.main(Flight.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: Why are you reading a line of the file into your `line` variable and then doing nothing with it? You're skipping every other line because of that.

Comment: Your `Passengers` class asks for 5 values but your txt file only contains 4 in each row.

Comment: I edited my question to answer that, perhaps I did this wrong? I'm very new to this, and its my first time nesting a loop within a loop... @JonK

Comment: Some have 4 and some have 3 in each row, I am also supposed to assign each seat to an associated 'seating class' within the flight according to the row in which they are seated, but I haven't gotten that far yet, until I solve this issue. @Turamarth

Comment: When i was learning about file reading in java i found some articles online. I think these articles will be very helpful: - https://www.baeldung.com/bufferedreader-vs-console-vs-scanner-in-java - https://www.baeldung.com/java-scanner-hasnext-vs-hasnextline -

Comment: I personally never ever use Scanner. Never. Read each line (which your code does), then parse the line myself. I split it at the delimiter (in your case, the comma) and then parse it out into the various fields myself. Remember -- your file isn't completely fixed. Some lines have more data. So when you try to read that data with Scanner, it's not there to read, and that leads to problems for you. You have to parse it yourself.